# UEFI bootable iso of own Linux distribution

Tags: distributions, iso, uefi

I have a Linux distribution that I want to create an ISO of, so I can put it onto a CD or USB. I have earlier used Remastersys and Relinux to create my own linux distributions, but the ISO they make are only bootable with legacy. Are there any software (payed or free) that's able to create an EFI bootable iso? Or how else can I make this ISO?

Comment: What about this? : http://code.google.com/p/pentoo/wiki/UEFI#UEFI_Creating_an_UEFI-bootable_ISO

Answer (score 1):

Very much advised to read [Rod Smith's excellent docs](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) and if you still need help, ask again (I've implemented UEFI support in ALT Linux -- there's [SecureBoot mini-HOWTO](http://en.altlinux.org/UEFI_SecureBoot_mini-HOWTO) but I didn't think that writing UEFI Boot one would be worth the time a year and a half ago given that enough tools and implementations were out there already).

Speaking of tools, you want:

- isohybrid-0.12 from syslinux-4.06 ([GPT/UEFI support](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/4957.html))
- recent xorriso (1.2.6 will do, 1.3.4 works even better for me)
- EFI toolchain (I use gnu-efi 3.0r/3.0u)
- EFI bootloader (elilo, refind, grub 2.00 with patches...)
- kernel with a few more options turned on (CONFIG_EFI, CONFIG_EFI_PARTITION, CONFIG_EFI_VARS, CONFIG_FB_EFI)
- gdisk or parted

Just in case, my mkimage-profiles project explicitly supports building UEFI-bootable hybrid images and lightweight customization (one doesn't have to fork anything over but just choose a close enough base and tweak it).  It's mostly documented in Russian for a reason though and uses ALT Linux package base as of today, [these starterkits](http://en.altlinux.org/Starterkits) are among its output.

Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks, Rod Smith's docs was very useful indeed. I have installed and made available all the tools you listed, but I have some issues understanding syslinux. I need the isolinux.cfg file. Is this file located somewhere, or do I have to create one myself? If so, is it possible to just copy the folder called isolinux from the standard ubuntu distro onto my own /boot/isolinux folder? Also, xorriso is causing also causing a bit of a pain, and I tried to do as explained in this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2176477 without any luck.